# iPhone 5s battery draining when in Airplane AND Sleep AND Low-power modes together, as if I am using it

Tags: iphone, battery, sleep-wake

My iPhone 5s battery is being drained very fast when in sleep mode (30-40% over night). I put it in airplane mode and in low power mode, and it still drains very fast in sleep mode. The battery however is fine during the day, lasts about 3/4 of my day when I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the battery health has degraded over time. I would recommend you install [Battery Life](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/battery-life-check-devices-runtimes/id1080930585?mt=8) in your iPhone to check the battery health.
If the battery health is below 80%, then you should consider replacing the battery. I replaced my iPhone 5's battery after 3-4 years after it hit 65% battery health. You should do the same. I was able to find a 3rd party battery and replace it myself. The process took me 30-40 mins. Also, go to the Battery section in the Settings app and see which apps are the biggest battery users.

Comment: Most of the programs showed 0% wear level (capacity 100%), one of them showed 3% wear level.

Comment: What about the battery usage stats? Which apps consume the most? You can also make certain apps use location services only when open via Settings app. That way there aren't too many apps using GPS in the background and possibly draining battery.

Comment: I also turn off location services and same happens.

Comment: Which apps are listed under the Battery section in the Settings app and what percentage of battery did they drain? Perhaps it could be some app using background services quite a bit. Did you try quitting all the apps before going to sleep at night?

Comment: Yes, I quit all apps almost always infact. Am a bit of an obsessive-compulsive.

Comment: Again...which apps are listed in the battery section of the Settings app? I asked this question several times but you only seem to respond to my last sentence.

Comment: Yes, although I don't think it's much use. slither.io 34%(44 min on screen), VTT-virtual table tennis 28%(33 min on screen) Phone 6%(21 min on screen), Home and lock screen 5%(11 min on screen) and so on....

Comment: That was for last 24 hours. For last 4 days stats are:
slither.io 36%(3.3 hours),VTT 24%(2.2 hours), WhatsApp 7%(52 min screen-49 min backgd), Home & Lock Screen 4%(1.1 hours on screen), Mail 3%(13 min screen - 11 min backgd) and so on...

Comment: This is a very odd issue. I honestly don't know why it drains faster overnight night than during the day. The only thing I know that drains battery overnight is the Sleep Cycle app that tracks motion as you sleep. If that's not the case, your best bet would be to leaving it charging overnight. That's what I always do. Nothing will happen to your battery if you do that because the iPhone charges at varied rates. Once it hits 80%, the rate of charging slows down. So your phone will do fine being charged overnight. Since even the Battery Life app said 0% wear level, the battery itself is fine

Comment: It doesn't drain faster, It drains the same no matter what I do. I don't play much games, but I use whatsapp , firefox browser and similar apps all the time, and it drains the same if I use it or if it just stays in sleep mode(which it does during the night). Also, during the night, it drains - I repeat - it drains the same in sleep mode, with airplane mode and low power mode turned on.

Comment: I meant faster than it should in sleep mode. Maybe uninstall unnecessary apps and reboot your device to clear memory. Also keep in mind that 5S is a very old model. I wouldn't be surprised if you are only getting half a day of battery. You should Google "iPhone battery drain sleep mode" and try the solutions they have to offer. It could potentially be a hardware failure.

Comment: Ok, I actually tried resetting my iPhone to factory settings, with same outcome.